# Trascendental extension

Tags: field-theory

Let $p$ a prime number  and let $\mathbf{F}_p(X)$ the field of rational functions over $\mathbf{F}_p$.

The degree $[\mathbf{F}_p(X):\mathbf{F}_p(X^p)]$ is $p$?

I'm a little confused; thanks.

Comment: This is a special case of [an earlier question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/924329/ftftn-n-where-t-is-trascendental), so I vote this to be a duplicate. However, that question has no accepted answer (even though it has good answers). So if those answers don't clear it up for you, do ask about a specific step.

Comment: For example, if $Y=p(X)/Q(X)$ with $P,Q\in\mathbf{F}_p[X]$; why
$\mathbf{F}_p(X)$ is algebraic over $\mathbf{F}_p(Y)$. 

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the polynomial $r(T):=P(T)-Y Q(T)$. Its coefficients are in the field $\mathbf{F}_p(Y)$, so it is in the ring $\mathbf{F}_p(Y)[T]$. Also $r(X)=P(X)-YQ(X)=0$, so $X$ is a zero of $r(T)$.

Comment: More precisely. In your case $P(X)=\sum_{i=0}^kp_iX^i$ and $Q(X)=\sum_{i=0}^nq_iX^i$ with $p_i,q_i\in\mathbf{F}_p$. Thus
$$r(T)=\sum_{i=0}^{\max\{k,n\}}(p_i-q_i Y)T^i.$$ We see that the coefficients of $r$ are in $\mathbf{F}_p(Y)$. Actually they are polynomials of degree $\le1$ in $Y$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen; Thanks.